# Jquery avoid normal buttons when selecting :submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say you have the following html document:

```
<form class="" ng-submit="CTRL.submit(CTRL.academy)" submit-throbber>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 b-r" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label translate="FORMS.NAME"></label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'FORMS.NAME_PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}"
                       ng-model="CTRL.academy.name" required="">
            </div>
            <label translate="FORMS.DESCRIPTION"></label>
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'FORMS.DESCRIPTION_PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}"
                      ng-model="CTRL.academy.description"
                      style="height: 300px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="lb-modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" tooltip="{{ 'TOOLTIP.CANCEL' | translate }}" ng-click="CTRL.cancel()"><i
            class="fa fa-ban"></i></button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success m-l-xs" tooltip="{{ 'TOOLTIP.SAVE_AND_EXIT' | translate }}"><i
            class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i></button>
</div>
```

now when i use jquery to find the submit button i do: `$('form').find(':submit')`

However in the above case it finds two results (both of my buttons)

This works correctly according to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/)

However is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: _"This works correctly according to the documentation"_ - only if you _"...specify a type property."_ for the first button. The documentation says to always specify a `type` property for buttons for this to work consistently. Add `type="button"` to your first non-submit button.

Comment: Of course it will have 2 results as both are `button` but one of them is having property `type=submit`, you should filter that. Similary if you want to select `div` element there are many but if you want a specific `div` you either give an `id` to that element or some property with unique value like `name="target"` or you can take help of pseudo selectors like `:first` ,':not' etc. if these applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$('form').find('[type=submit]')`

Answer (score 1):

As the docs you link to state:

> always specify a type property.

So just add `type="button"` on the cancel button and you should be good.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" tooltip="{{ 'TOOLTIP.CANCEL' | translate }}" ng-click="CTRL.cancel()"><i
            class="fa fa-ban"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('form').find("button[type='submit']");
```